# Import a c# project and run it in the background

Tags: c#, wpf, build, background

I'm making a WPF project which imports a c# project by browsing and building. Here's my small browsing and finding code:

```
var dialog2 = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result2 = dialog2.ShowDialog();
textBox1.Text = dialog2.SelectedPath;
```

After finding it by pressing a button I'm invoking this code:

```
Process.Start(textBox.Text);
```

This code runs the application directly. I need to build the application in the background.

I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: So you browse to a folder that contains sourcecode and you want to compile and run it?

Answer (score 1):

To build project from command line in background you can use `msbuild`

To find msbuild executable path on your system you can run registry query with:

```
reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0" /v MSBuildToolsPath
```

After you know the path, run the msbuild command to build your project. For example:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild SolutionName.sln
```

If you want to run your build command in the background start the process with `CreateNoWindow = true` For example:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild SolutionName.sln");
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\YourWorkingDirectory";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure what you mean by building the application in the background but I would suggest creating a library(e.g a DLL), build it and afterwards reference it from your other application.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the process class, there are some options. Firstly you could just bring your window back to the front. Second you could hide the window by using the startinfo showing no window, or minimizing it..

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What i understand from OP question, although is not very clear, is that his problem is building a solution from a path...